# Loading ff / ffbase files into R session with load.ffdf

Tags: r, ffbase

I have a large `ffdf` data frame saved to disk that I need to load into a fresh `R` session. When I run `load.ffdf` in the directory where the file is located, I get the following error message:

```
load.ffdf("./ffdb")
#    Error in `filename<-.ff`(`*tmp*`, value = "./custTrans$custKey.ff") : 
#    ff file rename from './custTrans$custKey.ff' to
#    'mylocation'/ffdb/custTrans$custKey.ff' failed
```

I really want to read these files. Is there a way to encourage them to be read? Is there some way to read the individual `ff` column-files directly? What format are they in? Perhaps I can place them manually in the temporary location that the underlying `ff` package uses?

I've had a look through the `save.ffdf` and `load.ffdf` functions, but that hasn't given me any easy fixes.

Backgroud: I originally saved the data frame `custTrans` to the default `./ffdb` directory. I actually wanted them in directory `./custTrans`, so I used `move.ffdf` to move the files. The column files were moved, but not the `.RData` and `.Rprofile` files. I have tried to load the data from `./ffdb` directory and also copied the `.RData` and `.Rprofile` files to the `./custTrans` directory and run `load.ffdf` there. I have also tried to move the data files back to the `./ffdb` directory. The error message is the same.

Comment: I've added a working fix to my problem, but I would love to understand more how this *should* be done and what went wrong in my case! (Or: What I was doing wrong.)

Comment: I think the best for your case would be to move your data back in the original directory. Do load.ffdf of the data and save.ffdf to the directory you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a part-solution to the problem. I can now read the raw `ff` files using `readBin`. Since my `ffdf` *is* loaded into the search path, I can use it to see what the specific data types in my columns were, as well as the column lengths. Printing the object gives me the information.

```
custTrans
```

Then `readBin`, with `what` and `n` set according to the information printed above, will read the files. Then can them be combined back into an `ffdf` using standard methodology.

```
custKey <- readBin("./custTrans/MINS$custKey.ff", what = "int", n = 268820)
Transactiondate.max <- readBin("./custTrans/MINS$Transactiondate.max.ff",
                               what = "double", n = 268820)
Transactiondate.min <- readBin("./custTrans/MINS$Transactiondate.min.ff",
                               what = "double", n = 268820)
custTrans <- as.ffdf(as.ff(custKey),
                     as.ff(Transactiondate.max),
                     as.ff(Transactiondate.min))
```

This obviously assumes all this fits into memory, which it does. (It was not the size of the files that were a problem, but the generating them took a very long time.)